# Inline import the default export into array

Tags: ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I have multiple files called `PageX`, `PageY`, `PageZ` etc.

Each of these have an `export default SETUP { path:'blah_X', component:X }`.

In my index.js I want to import these `SETUP`s into an array like this:

```
const PAGE_SETUPS = [
   import './PageX',
   import './PageY',
   import './PageZ' 
];

const routes = PAGE_SETUPS.map(setup => createElement(Route, {path:setup.path, component:setup.component});
```

I am hitting all kinds of issues. Is this possible to inline-import the `default` exported item into an array like this?

Comment: Did you mean `export default SETUP({…});` or `export default const SETUP = {…};`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, there are no "inline imports" in ES6 modules. You can either use whichever kind of non-declarative import method the module loading system that you transpile to offers, or you have to spell it out:

```
import PageX from './PageX',
import PageY from './PageY',
import PageZ from './PageZ' 
const PAGE_SETUPS = [PageX, PageY, PageZ];
```

Comment: Darn, ok thank you. Also doing `export default const = blah` doesnt work. It seems it has to be `export default = blah` (without the `const`).

Comment: @Noitidart `const` is a keyword that starts a variable declaration, and you need to supply an identifier name. You can use `export default const myVarName = …;` or `export {myVariableName as default}; const myVariableName = …;` - but you don't need to do that at all, since the default export is not assignable.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is have this be in a pages directory with an index.mjs file alongside all your pages. Then you can import all your pages and export the array. From that index file you could export an array of your pages and import that in another module.

```js
// pages/index.js
import PageX from './PageX',
import PageY from './PageY',
import PageZ from './PageZ' 
export const PAGE_SETUPS = [PageX, PageY, PageZ];
```

Then you would just need to import your array in another file.

```js
//some other module
import PAGE_SETUPS from './pages/index.mjs'
const routes = PAGE_SETUPS
```

Alternatively you could pass your modules through the original `page/index.js` file instead of exporting an array.

```js
// pages/index.js
export * from './PageX',
export * from './PageY',
export * from './PageZ'
```

```js
// some other module
import {PageX, PageY, PageZ} from './pages/index.mjs'

const routes = [
  PageX,
  PageY, 
  PageZ
]
```