# Dynamic import of react-icons

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Is it possible to import dynamically react-icons if each of icon is a separate component?
My code looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';

import { Icon1, Icon2, Icon3, Icon4 } from 'react-icons/ri';

const Foo = () => (
  <div className="xxx">
    <div className="y">
      <Icon1 />
    </div>
    <div className="y">
      <Icon2 />
    </div>
    <div className="y">
      <Icon3 />
    </div>
    <div className="y">
      <Icon4 />
    </div>
  </div>
);

export default Foo;
```

and would want it to look close to this:

import React from 'react';

```
const Buttons = () => {
  const iconsList = ['Icon1', 'Icon2', 'Icon3'];
  const renderIcon = (icon) => {
   const Icon = icon;
   return (
    <div className="y">
     <Icon />
    </div>
   )
  }

  return (
   <div className="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-end">
    {iconsList.map(icon => renderIcon(icon))}
   </div>
 )
};

export default Buttons;
```

The problem I face is how to make the import of icons work there if I didn't want to import all icons using `*`.
Also the problem is that if I make

```
import { Icon1, Icon2, Icon3, Icon4 } from 'react-icons/ri'
```

at the top, it still doesn't work for the second version of code.

Comment: have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42595264/inline-import-the-default-export-into-array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to replace the strings values of your icons in the `iconsList` array with the Icon component itself.

**Just change :**

```
const iconsList = ['Icon1', 'Icon2', 'Icon3'];
```

**to :**

```
const iconsList = [Icon1, Icon2, Icon3];
```

And add a key to prevent `Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.`**Warning** like this  :

```
{iconsList.map((icon, index) => renderIcon(icon, index))}
```

**and  :**

```
const renderIcon = (icon, index) => {
    const Icon = icon;
    return (
      <div className="y" key={index}>
        <Icon />
      </div>
    );
  };
```

this is an example in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/combobox-material-demo-forked-6k17zg?file=/index.js)

**Note :** If you import all icons using  `*`  , you're importing hundreds of icons at once which is probably not ideal.